# Where can I find reliable and up-to-date information about ongoing curfews in Myanmar?

Tags: online-resources, nightlife, myanmar, war-zones, curfews

There are (were?) some curfews in Myanmar due to the [Myanmar civil war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myanmar_civil_war_(2021%E2%80%93present)) that started in 2021. When I Google "curfews in Myanmar", I see many results, but these are typically [old news articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJjtU.png). I have no idea if the information is still accurate. Where can I find reliable and up-to-date information about ongoing curfews in Myanmar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Facebook, you can ask questions in a group called Yangon Connection (I'm not sure if the group is still active) or similar groups. Curfew information isn't typically found in news articles, as announcements about the curfew are primarily posted on the current "military government" official Facebook page.

The curfew announcements are also made through public address announcements, which involve verbal notifications broadcasted through speakers in public areas. As far as I am aware, Yangon currently does not have a curfew, but it's advisable not to go out after 5 pm.